# Given a, too big for memory, non-sorted csv file, how can one search through and increment a specific row in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, csv, search

Example of csv file:

```
hash, move, count
123456789, d4, 1
123456789, d3, 4
987654321, Ra3, 2
987654321, d4, 3
```

As seen, a hash or move can occur on multiple rows, but the combination of the two is unique and can therefore not happen on more than one row.

The search should match both the hash and move of the row to the search criteria and then increment the count. A search with the criteria of `hash: 123456789, move: d4` should give the end result after the search of:

```
hash, move, count
123456789, d4, 2
123456789, d3, 4
987654321, Ra3, 2
987654321, d4, 3
```

The process can be either synchronous or asynchronous, although i would prefer the former.

I have tried using a read stream, but I cannot figure how to edit the line once it is found.

Comment: kinda sounds like you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job if the csv is that large.

Comment: If csv is the wrong tool, what would be the right tool?